# C++ Shared-memory necessary for queue of std::strings to pass through JNI?

Tags: c++, linux, java-native-interface, semaphore, shared-memory

I'm trying to understand what the mechanism is for getting a string from a c++ daemon I've written to Java for use by a UI.  I'll post a picture of what I envision, then continue the question afterward:

[image]

There are two issues that I envision here:

1) The semaphore needs to be available to the library.  In Windows, that could've been done with a named semaphore and access to it's handle.  In Linux, I've been pointed toward using a semaphore in shared memory and making processes aware of it through a key to the shared memory.  It's vague to me, but will that concept work to synchronize Java and the daemon?

2)  Do I have to place the queue in shared memory in order to make the `???` link in the above chart work?  Can and should the queue reside in the .so?

So those are my concerns.  I'd love and welcome any and all help, challenges, and pleas for sanity and will do my best to provide all additionally necessary information.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be much easier to use sockets (UNIX-domain perhaps) for this task, and forget about JNI.

Comment: Or pipes, if you are more comfortable with them.

Comment: I'm in an embedded environment with a control card managing multiple telnet interfaces to expansion cards. The Java layer was added as a means for getting data from the browser-based UI to the underlying hardware control software, written in C++. It might not be elegant, but I came into this project post-design. Is it feasible, if perhaps difficult?

Answer (score 0):

You're running both applications in a separate process, in vanilla Linux this means you cannot communicate between these processes via memory directly. The Java VM is a process, and the C++ daemon is a process. It's in separate memory locations which are btw scrambled by the Memory Manager (MMU). So there is no way of getting memory access.

Google on "inner process communication" if you'd like. I prefer to run with socketpair for bi-directional parent-child communication.